# How give parent in navigation-structure the active tag

Tags: structure, navigation

So I have a two-level Navigation in a structure. What I want is to give the parent of my entry (if a parent exists) the active tag.

right now I'm doing that:

```
{% for nav_item in navigation %}
  <li class="{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == nav_item.nav_url %}active {% endif %}{% if nav_item.hasDescendants() %}more{% endif %}">

    <a href="{{nav_item.nav_url}}">{{nav_item.title}}</a>

  {% if nav_item.hasDescendants() %}
    <ul class="submenu">
      {% for child in nav_item.getChildren() %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{child.nav_url}}">{{child.title}}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

sadly most children don't share the first segment

Answer (score 1):

How a look at the [`isAncestorOf()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#isAncestorOf) method in the Docs. The given example code probably covers all you need:

```
{% set expanded = entry is defined and page.isAncestorOf(entry) %}
<li{% if expanded %} class="expanded"{% endif %}>
```

To only address the direct parent, use [`isParentOf()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#isParentOf) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you to use the URL segments for comparisons, I posted an answer on how to do that here: ["How can I add a dynamic “active” CSS class to the navigation on any given page?"](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2233/125)

Comment: Sorry, only read that relevant line at the bottom of your post after posting this. Hopefully that other answer I just gave is more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Entries field type in your navigation structure [(like the more advanced example in this post on the craft cookbook](http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/88)) you should be able to use the relatedTo( ) parameter to do the comparison instead of using the segment in a URL.

For example if you had an Entries Field with the handle "relatedEntry" in your navigation structure you could change your code from this:

```
  <li class="{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == nav_item.nav_url %}active {% endif %}{% if nav_item.hasDescendants() %}more{% endif %}">
```

to this:

```
{# Fetch the related navigation entry based on our current entry #}
{% set relatedToEntry = navigation.relatedTo(entry)%}

{# Check to see if the mainNavigation entry matches the current entry. Only compare it with the top level navigation items #}
{% set active = (relatedToEntry[0].slug == nav_item.slug and nav_item.hasDescendants) or (relatedToEntry[0].parent != "" and relatedToEntry[0].parent.slug == nav_item.slug) %}

{# display the class "active" if #}
<li class="{% if active %}active {% endif %}{% if nav_item.hasDescendants() %}more{% endif %}">
<a href="{{ nav_item.relatedEntry[0].url }}">{{ nav_item.title }}</a></li>
```

Note: For some reason I had to compare the slugs (as opposed to the names) in order to get a positive match.