# How to add active class to homepage nav list item

Tags: templating

Someone provided a solution, via the Craft Google community, but it was suggested that I also post it here for others to use.

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'homepage' %} class="active" {% endif %}>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('work') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'work' %} class="active" {% endif %}>Work</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('about') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'about' %} class="active" {% endif %}>About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The above was adapted from the demo site install (I think) and although 'work' and 'about' work fine 'homepage' did not.  I used 'homepage' as this is the 'handle' in the craft sections part of the cms so I thought that would be correct.

I initially found this [How can I add a dynamic "active" CSS class to the navigation on any given page?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-can-i-add-a-dynamic-active-css-class-to-the-navigation-on-any-given-page) but not being that dev focused found the many alternatives a bit confusing.

It was suggested that I add a 'section' to the homepage template and so I added `{% set section = "home" %}` after `{% extends "_layout" %}` in the homepage  index.html.

I then amended my first `<li>` from above to be just

```
<li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}" {% if section == 'home' %} class="active" {% endif %}>Home</a></li>
```

which worked as required.

I hope that helps.

If anyone can explain why my original doesn't work, in layman's terms that would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Laurence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the URL is `domainname.com/homepage` then your class will not get added.

Are you using template layouts? If you are you could have something like this in your `_layout`

```
{% block bodyClass %}{% if bodyClass is defined %}<body class="{{ bodyClass }}">
{% else %}<body>
{% endif %}
```

Then in your `home` template you would set it like so:

```
{% set bodyClass = 'CLASSNAME' %}
```

OR you could something like this in your nav:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == '' %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('work') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'work' %} class="active" {% endif %}>Work</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('about') }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == 'about' %} class="active" {% endif %}>About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

### #

Hopefully that helps. If not you can always look at this post with other methods:

[How can I add a dynamic "active" CSS class to the navigation on any given page?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/554/how-can-i-add-a-dynamic-active-css-class-to-the-navigation-on-any-given-page)

Comment: Thanks Mark, you somehow read my mind as I was interested in finding out how to add a class to the body as well. `<li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}" {% if craft.request.firstSegment == '' %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</a></li>` worked to solve my original question me.

Comment: Awesome :) I'm glad I could help, now just mark my response as an answer :)